# Multivariate time-series regression with neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, time-series

I have a dataset, where X is three dimensional matrix with 760 (different id/individuals) x 300000 (electrophysiological time series data) x 15 (number of different channels). I have a continuous, numerical y which is unique to each of the individuals (N=760). I have to predict y from X (obviously...).

I'd like to use deep neural networks for this purpose, but I kind of lost in choosing the right model.
RNN/LSTM could be good, but it's just for forecasting the time series itself and not regression. I'm not sure whether a convolutional neural net could detect changes in time (reshaping X into a 760x4500000 matrix).

Could you suggest some valid approaches for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for either CNNs or LSTMs.

CNNs can actually be used for time series analysis and may provide better results than expected.

I provide here below an example which illustrates how convolution can be applied on time series.

[image: An overview of 1D Convolution on time series data]

The alternative is to use LSTMs/GRUs. I do not add here a description since, as compared to 1D CNNs, they are much better described on the internet.

Two things to note here are:

1. That both(CNNs and LSTMs) can be used for classification purposes.
2. Using neural networks would be an optimal choice due to having multi-variate regression.